Find some better algorithm for finding the smallest difference between the elements of an array
Input: Array of integers A[0..n – 1]
Output: Smallest difference between two elements of a dmin array
dmin = ∞
for i = 0 to n − 1 do
   for j = 0 to n − 1 do
      if i != j &&|A[i] − A[j]| < dmin
        dmin ← |A[i] − A[j]|
return dmin
  

I know the complexity of the above code is O(n^2). I want to find a better algorithm for
finding the smallest difference between the elements of an array and find the complexity of it. Then, implement the above code as a single function and your improved algorithm as another function in c. Call the two functions for random arrays of size 60000, 70000, 80000, 90000 and 100000 (for each dimension create ten different random matrices and find the mean).
So, i have done:
int pair1(int A[],int n)
{
    int dmin=INT_MAX,i,j;
   
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if (i != j && abs(A[i] - A[j]) < dmin) 
            {
                dmin = abs(A[i] - A[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return dmin;
}

I thought a better algorithm might be if we sorted the array. Any ideas how to do this in c and how to write it as a pseydocode? I think that the complexity of it would be O(nlogn).
I have tried this code:
int pair2(int A[],int n)
{
    int dmin=INT_MAX,i,j;
    sort(A,A+n);

    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)
        {
            if (i != j && abs(A[i] - A[j]) < dmin) 
            {
                dmin = abs(A[i] - A[j]);
            }
        }
    }
        
    return dmin;
}


One efficiency could be to change for(j=0; j<n-1; j++) to for(j=i+1; j<n-1; j++). Because with the absolute difference you repeat pairs already checked.

Perhaps if you sort the array first, then the test needs a single pass of the data.

By all appearances, you have a homework assignment or similar learning exercise, and you are asking about multiple things: What is a good algorithm, how do you implement it, and how do you write C code? That is too broad to ask on Stack Overflow. Indeed, sorting the array and then looking for the two closest elements in it is likely a good enough answer for the assigned exercise. By the time you are assigned an exercise like this, you ought to be able to write the C code for each of the parts. Take the time to do that, working on one part at a time…

… If you must, then ask on Stack Overflow about one specific part. Not the whole exercise. And only after looking elsewhere—there are plenty of resources that will show you how to write a decent sort routine in C or how to call the standard library sort routine, and then writing a loop to find which two elements in the sorted list are closest should be simple.

(For anybody interested in going further, I wonder whether some improvement is available in considering ideas from a Quicksort or the Selection Algorithm to find close elements without doing a full sort. E.g., pick a random element, partition the array into elements above it and below it (without sorting them fully), find the closest two elements in each partition (possibly in a recursive-like way), and take the minimum of those or the two that straddle the partition.)

When you sort it, you don't need nested loops. Just get the minimum of abs(A[i] - A[i+1])

...in pair2() this j<n-1; is wrong. The code also has i<n-1 so element n-1 is never considered.

@WeatherVane Sorting the list first then checking can be optimized by tracking the differences while sorting - the act of sorting requires effectively the same calculations as the difference of the values so there's no need to repeat them. Offhand, I suspect an insertion sort would work well enough.

@AndrewHenle can that be done without actually sorting the array? But as if it is sorted (saving the time of moving elements around).

@WeatherVane If you used a linked list or similar, you wouldn't have to move any elements.  Maybe even better, insert into a b-tree, with each node keeping track of the min and max values on each side of the tree beneath it.  If the input values are random, I think such a b-tree would be much more efficient and might even allow quick calculation of the min difference.  And FWIW, given the size of the arrays here, RAND_MAX better be some value significantly greater than the 32767 mandated by the C standard or the min difference will always be zero...

(cont)  If RAND_MAX isn't large enough, the calculations are trivial: if ( numberOfValues >= RAND_MAX ) { minDiff = 0; }

@AndrewHenle Isn't insertion sort O(N^2)? OP wants better (suggested: O(Nlog2(N)). So, with (e.g. quicksort/mergesort), the minimum difference scan pass can be O(N), so total is O(Nlog2(N)). And, the mean could be done in the same O(N) pass. [Without thinking about it too much], what am I missing? If we can't sort the original array, we could make a copy or an array of indirect pointers/indices into the original array.

To OP: Can the array values be negative? If generated from (e.g.) rand, they will always be positive. If all values are positive, with a sorted array, we can eliminate the abs.

If the range of integers in the array is small then you can sort it in O(n) time with https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/data-structure-tutorial/counting-sort-algorithm and the whole thing would take O(n) time.

The absolute value of the difference between 2 int values may exceed the range of int, one must use unsigned for this and so should the return type  be.
Sorting the array is indeed a good way to reduce the time complexity from quadratic to N.log(N).
Here is a solution:
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare_ints(const void *aa, const void *bb)
{
    const int *a = aa;
    const int *b = bb;
    return (*a > *b) - (*a < *b);
}

unsigned pair2(const int A[], size_t n)
{
    // special case the empty set and singletons
    if (n <= 1)
        return 0;

    // sort the array
    qsort(A, n, sizeof(*A), compare_ints);

    unsigned dmin = UINT_MAX;

    // find the smallest difference between successive entries
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        unsigned diff = (unsigned)A[i] - (unsigned)A[i - 1];
        if (dmin > diff)
            dmin = diff;
    }
    return dmin;
}


The if (A[i] >= A[i - 1]) check is superfluous as that is guaranteed by sorting.

@Unmitigated: yes of course! silly me.

Yes, you are correct that the minimum difference can found in O(n*log2(n)) if you sort the array with an O(n*log2(n)) sorting algorithm such as quicksort or mergesort.
Then, finding the minimum difference is a single loop of O(n).
Together the complexity is the greater of the two: O(n*log2(n))
Here is some sample code. It is heavily annotated:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int
cmp(const void *vlhs,const void *vrhs)
{
    const int *lhs = vlhs;
    const int *rhs = vrhs;
    return (*lhs > *rhs) - (*lhs < *rhs);
}

int
pair2(int A[],int n)
{

    // sort the array by any O(n*log2(n)) [or better] sort (e.g. quicksort,
    // mergesort)
    qsort(A,n,sizeof(int),cmp);

    int dmin = INT_MAX;

    // get A[i - 1] for first loop iteration
    int old = A[0];

    // loop through all remaining elements (this is O(n))
    for (int i = 1;  i < n;  ++i) {
        // get the current array value
        int cur = A[i];

        // difference between the current and previous values:
        // dif = A[i] - A[i - 1]
        int dif = cur - old;

        // get absolute value
        if (dif < 0)
            dif = -dif;

        // save new/better minimum
        if (dif < dmin) {
            dmin = dif;

            // because we took the absolute value, we can't get any better than
            // this
            if (dif == 0)
                break;
        }

        // remember A[i - 1] for next iteration
        old = cur;
    }

    return dmin;
}


I'm afraid return *rhs - *lhs; is not correct as the expression will cause an arithmetic overflow if the difference exceeds the range of type int.  You should use return (*lhs > *rhs) - (*lhs < *rhs);  The loop in main to compute the smallest difference has the same problem.  You can simply use long long arithmetics for a quick solution but it would not suffice on systems where sizeof (int) == sizeof(long long)

@chqrlie yes, was in a hurry. Fixed. Thanks.

still incorrect for A[] = { INT_MIN, INT_MAX };

dmin should probably be unsigned... (@chqrlie beat me to the punch as I sat scratching my head, hesitating over clicking "submit"...)

@Fe2O3: yes, unsigned would suffice as the return type, but computing the smallest difference is still a bit tricky.

A small point: I think one would normally see O(n*log2(n)) written O(n*log(n)) as converting the log of a value from one base to another merely requires the multiplication of the first by a constant (e.g., log2(n) = log2(10) * log10(n)).

@CarySwoveland In addition, log2(n) looks very similar to log^2(n).

Quicksort's worst case is O(n^2); if you were working with the worst case (or on an assignment), better use mergesort.

@Neil Yes, I'm not a fan of quicksort for that reason (and that it's not a stable sort). qsort is ubiquitous. However, I recently found that (newer versions of) glibc's qsort will use mergesort under the hood under certain circumstances. In particular, if the sizeof is large (e.g. > 32), qsort uses "indirect sorting" that involves an internal version of mergesort. It reverts to internal quicksort if the memory requirements for mergesort are "too high"

@CarySwoveland mergesort has n*log2(n) comparisons. Granted that when applying O(x) the time is "logarithmic", so we could use log(n), but, it seemed clearer to use the exact logarithm rather than to have to explain that.

@Neil Although it's strictly internal in glibc, it appears that freebsd has a fully exported mergesort in stdlib.h

While the sort qsort uses is unspecified, in practice, most use Bently McIlroy 1993 Engineering. (The size-dependant median-of-medians partition, among other tweaks, is very resistant to quadratic run-time in practice.)

@Neil I just rechecked glibc. It tries to use mergesort and if it falls back to quicksort, it does use Bently McIIroy. Personally, I'd like an exported mergesort that allows one to specify the temp area as an arg. And, whether the arg is big enough for sizeof or just indirect (i.e. the sizeof is for a pointer). IIRC, perl's sort was quicksort but is now mergesort [because they were getting complaints about it not being a stable sort?]. perl's mergesort is based on a 1993 paper by Peter M. McIlroy [any relation?]
